# Differences between ways of affecting data connected to a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there are any differences(security or performance or bad practice wise) of data where the data is connected to a primary key. So basically lets say you have a database like this:

**users**

```
id | username | password
```

**posts**

```
id | post | user_id
```

Now lets say we have a post linked to a user. We have a page where we delete the post for example. So we would run a query like this for example when you click the delete button:

```
DELETE FROM posts where id=5;
```

Now the flaw in just executing this is, you could manipulate the `GET` value `id` as a user.

The way I learned to prevent this is to just check it by doing another check on wether the user id of that post is the same as the id of the user currently logged in with PHP and another query.

But I recently tried another way by just changing the query like this:

```
DELETE FROM posts where id=5 and userid=1;
```

If you want a message to know if you deleted something you could just get the number of affected row. My friend told me this is very bad practice, I could see that being but in what way is this worse than the first method? (Assuming in both cases sql injection would be prevented). What are the overall differences?

Comment: Are you saying you would pass in the user id as a get parameter as well? Or are you saying that you would get the user id from the logged in user?

Comment: @AdamForbis Im talking about adding the userid in the query in the AND part. So when someone manipulates the id of the post (trying to delete someone else his post) it wouldnt delete it cause it would also automatically check on the user_id of the person thats logged in. So getting the user id from the logged in user

Comment: Would you ever need to handle a case where an administrator account could delete the post? Then they wouldn't have the same user id.

Comment: @AdamForbis Nope never. In this case I would just delete it in the database.

Comment: This is basic security, but not really anything related to foreign keys. I see nothing wrong in either approaches. The first one is handy if you need further checks, the second one is simpler if you don't need them.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your approaches either, and I can't think of any reason it would impact performance. As for bad practice, things like that can sometimes be subjective, so you might have to post your friends reasoning to his claim to get any decent answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález My friend said it makes no sense to run a query when you could already know beforehand that the user does something wrong and not send a query at all.